# How To Split Up Digits Into Character Array

Tags: bash, shell, scripting

I'm a bit stuck with something. I have a for loop like this:

```
#!/bin/bash
for i in {10..15}
do
```

I want to obtain the last digit of the number, so if i is 12, I want to get 2. I'm having difficulties with the syntax though. I've read that I should convert it into a character array, but when I do something like:

```
j=${i[@]}
echo $j
```

I don't get 1 0 1 1 1 2 and so on...I get 10, 11, 12...How do I get the numbers to be split up so I can get the last one of i, when I don't always know how many digits will make up i (ex. it may be 1, or 10, or a 100, etc.)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Trick is to treat `$i` like a string.

```
for i in {10..15}; do j="${i: -1}"; echo $j; done
```

Of course, you do not need to assign to a variable if you don't want to:

```
for i in {10..15}; do echo "${i: -1}"; done
```

Comment: Thank you @Frank! This worked perfectly for all numbers.

Answer (score 1):

This `awk` command could solve your problem:

`awk '{print substr($0,length,1)}' test_file`

I'm assuming that the numbers are saved in a file  `test_file`

If you want to use `for` loop:

```
for i in `cat test_1`
do
echo $i |tail -c 2
done
```

Comment: Doesn't this look like an overkill?

Comment: Overkill?..I didn't get it.

Comment: I just meant to say there could be a more easy method than this. :) Also, there is nothing in the question that says the numbers are stored in a text file. Even if they are stored in a text file, you could use shell built-ins to manipulate them. Since `cat` is an external executable, I have a feel that `for i in \`cat test_1\`` is neither the best nor the recommended method to parse the text file.

Comment: Also `cat test_file | awk '{print substr($0,length,1)}'` could well be replaced like `awk '{print substr($0,length,1)}' test_file`

Answer (score 1):

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50323121/1620779) answer which uses [GNU shell parameter expansion](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Shell-Parameter-Expansion.html) is the most sensible method, I guess.

However, you can also use [the double parenthesis construct](http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/dblparens.html#DBLPARENS) which allows C-style manipulation of variables in Bash.

```
for i in {10..15}
do
 (( j =  i % 10 )) # modulo 10 always gives the ones' digit
 echo $j
done
```